# The difference between Application.Dispatcher and Window.Dispatcher...?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, multithreading

Let me introduce that I am not completely new to WPF, but today I discovered something I don't know how it works, I am giving a brief of what I did.

I was writing a C# WPF code where I need to populate the `ObservableCollection` based on certain criteria and display the content in the UI, So in the `ViewModel` I started a `BackgroundWorker` thread

```
 BackgroundWorker bgwRoot = new BackgroundWorker();
 bgwRoot.DoWork +=  bgwRoot_DoWork(filepath);
 bgwRoot.RunWorkerAsync();
 bgwRoot.RunWorkerCompleted += bgwRoot_RunWorkerCompleted;
```

the thread will keep updating the observable collection and when all completed the BackgroundWorker finishes its job.

Here I want to point out that `FilesCollections = new ObservableCollection<FileListCollections>();` is created in the `MainThread`

so in the `bgwRoot_DoWork()` cannot directly update the `ObservableCollection` I can understand that. So I used `BeginInvoke`

```
Application.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Action(() => this.FilesCollections.Add(myItem)));
```

But When debug I discovered that Application.Current object is `null`. And Finally as a solution I pass the Window object from codeBehind and solved this problem. 
The solution is

1. Create an object of the Window class

   `public pUserControl userControl;`
2. and instatiate it in the `ViewModel`

   `userControl = pUserControl;`
3. And finally

`userControl.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Action(() =>

              this.FilesCollections.Add(myItem)));`

So my question is when I shall use `Application.Current.Dispatcher`? 
In what cases it actually solves the threading problem? Because if I write a code in ViewModel to update any `Collections` and keep a `progressbar` in the UI, there is no point VM knows anything about `View` Object.

So When to use `Application.Current.Dispatcher.beginInvoke()`? and when to use `userControl.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke()`?

Please help.

Comment: if your `System.Windows.Application.Current` is null you're going to have serious problems down the road. I suggest you fix that. That said, the Application.Current.Dispatcher most probably ReferenceEquals() the Window.Dispatcher almost always, meaning they're one and the same.

Comment: That said, I also suggest you forget the BackgroundWorker approach and use async/await instead, which is much cleaner.

Comment: @HighCore, if `Application.Current.Dispatcher` and `Window.Dispatcher` both are same then why application.Current is null? Any idea in what cases it could be null? When I replaced with Window.Dispatcher it works perfectly.

Comment: It will be null when you start the BGW too soon, before the Application object is initialized.   Unclear how you did that, maybe you want to use the Application.Startup event.

Comment: @HansPassant or maybe there's something else going on there such as the application not starting with a `System.Windows.Application` but instead some custom entry point or even a winforms app, but yeah I'd check when is that being run fist.

Comment: This ui is a UserControl, and this usercontrol we are showing in the UI when the BGW finishes it jobs. The application object is initialized but Application.Current is null.

Comment: *"so in the bgwRoot_DoWork() cannot directly update the ObservableCollection I can understand that. "* why not? In wpf the UI automaticly will dispatch to the ui the thread if the collection was changed on a background thread

Comment: @HighCore Many UI technologies enable IU change via a single thread, that was used to create the UI due to graphics driver limitations. Using a dispatcher lets you multi thread, yet update the UI (the view models) via the UI thread. Using await for long running processes will leave your UI unresponsive.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain a. `ObservableCollection`'s are single threaded. b. The automatic dispatch depends on the binding.

Comment: @DannyVarod No they are not thread safe for writing. That is different than single threaded. As long as you only have one writer it can be from any thread (This situation is the exact reason [`ReaderWriterLock`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.readerwriterlockslim.aspx) was written), it does not need to be the same thread that it was created on (like most UI controls). Also the automatic dispatch is from any kind of binding, I can't think of one where you don't get automatic dispatch.

Comment: @DannyVarod you seem not to understand how async/await works. You're wrong. async/await does not make the UI unresponsive at all.

Comment: @HighCore You're right, I confused it with task.Wait()