# WPF - Set Window Owner

Tags: wpf

I have the following case:

- A window is shown the the reference to that is stored in a utility class.
- Later a modal dialog needs to appear *above* that window; so I am doing the following:

  ```
  OptionalMessageBox message = new OptionalMessageBox(title, errorMessage.ToString(), MessageImage.Warning);
  if (UIUtilities.TopWindow != null)
  {
      UIUtilities.TopWindow.Dispatcher.Invoke(() => message.Owner = UIUtilities.TopWindow);
      UIUtilities.TopWindow.Dispatcher.Invoke(() => message.ShowDialog());
  }
  else
  {
      message.ShowDialog();
  }
  ```

However this is give the classic 'The calling thread cannot access this object because a different thread owns it' though I don't understand why as I am using the dispatcher for the TopWindow variable.  As a note (and out of desperation) I tried putting the calls on the message variable I just created - that didn't work either but I didn't expect that to be the problem as how can I now own it if I have just made it!

Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
if (UIUtilities.TopWindow != null)
{
    UIUtilities.TopWindow.Dispatcher.Invoke(() => 
    {
        var message = new OptionalMessageBox(title, errorMessage.ToString(), MessageImage.Warning);
        message.Owner = UIUtilities.TopWindow;
        message.ShowDialog();
    });
}
else
{
    var message = new OptionalMessageBox(title, errorMessage.ToString(), MessageImage.Warning);
    message.ShowDialog();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this

```
App.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke(() => {
OptionalMessageBox message = new OptionalMessageBox(title, errorMessage.ToString(), MessageImage.Warning);
message.Owner = App.Current.MainWindow;
message.ShowDialog();
});
```

Comment: Thanks but that requires the ability to access App - the other answer removes that requirement.

Comment: You can always access App. Note that "Application.Current.Dispatcher most probably ReferenceEquals() the Window.Dispatcher almost always, meaning they're one and the same" see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28703717/the-difference-between-application-dispatcher-and-window-dispatcher

Comment: Also note that in the other answer, it will not display the message if TopWindow is null. This is not what is asked in the question.

Comment: I can access Application; however if TopWindow is null then I still get the message behind the current window so therefore I need to use TopMost (not ideal but the best I can do quickly).  My main aim is to make the dialog on the top in my application.  The only way I can think of doing it right now is to have a stack onto which I push each window every time one is opened; then peek the stack to set the owner.  I'm used to having modal windows for an entire application in other GUI frameworks but it seems that WPF doesn't have it - do you know if there is an easy way to do this at all please?

Comment: @NeilBenn can you use _message.Topmost = true_ in the second line of my code? I mean, is OptionalMessageBox  a Window?

Comment: Yes it is but the problem is that topmost=true puts the window on top of everything in the entire OS; I only want to be on the top in my application.  I cannot see an easy way to do that.